# Separately ordering two queries and then joining them

Tags: mysql

I am designing a comment system where users first see their comments (newest first) and then any other users comments (newest first). So in the end it would look like:

1. My Comment 1 (Dec 3)
2. My Comment 2 (Dec 2)
3. My Comment 3 (Dec 1)
4. Not My Comment 1 (Dec 5)
5. Not My Comment 2 (Dec 4)
6. Not My Comment 3 (Dec 3)

So to pull the info from the table I have:

```
SELECT * FROM ( SELECT * FROM testTable WHERE me='1' ORDER BY `lastReply` DESC ) DUMMY1
UNION
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM testTable ORDER BY `lastReply` DESC) DUMMY2
```

This does what I want only instead of ordering by lastReply descending (so the users newest comment is first) it instead orders by lastReply ascending (so the users oldest comment is first). 
For the life of me I can't figure out why this is happening. Any advice?

You can view a simplified version of the table here:

```
mysqli_query($con," CREATE TABLE testTable( text varchar(255), me varchar(255), lastReply varchar(255) ) "); 
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO testTable (text, me , lastReply) VALUES ('A',1,3),('E',0,2),('C',1,1) , ('D',0,1) , ('B',1,2) ,('F',0,3) ");


echo '<table border="1">';
while($arrayrow = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo '<tr><td>'.$arrayrow['text'].'</td><td>'.$arrayrow['me'].'</td><td>'.$arrayrow['lastReply'].'</td></tr>';
};
echo '</table>';
```

Comment: Do you want a computed label which distinguishes user from non-user comments in your output?

Comment: I'm not sure what that means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * from (
SELECT *,0 as sort_order FROM table WHERE IP='userIP'
UNION
SELECT *,1 as sort_order FROM table WHERE IP <>'userIP' 
)tmp
ORDER by sort_order asc, lastReply Desc
```

Comment: This code throws a "Incorrect usage of UNION and ORDER BY " error.

Comment: please try  now  :)

Comment: That's got it. Thanks for the help. For my own knowledge though, what does the `*,0` and `*,1` do in this case?

Comment: 0,1, are Just to make custom sort . 0 is for your post and 1 is for others . So, whenever you sort by that custom field, your posts will come 1st followed by others.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen : your answer and my answer are quite similar but its not a copy , your second query dont  have any condition so it will  give duplicate Cartesian products which will be non duplicate while doing union , and it will slow down the sql a bit. Try with EXPLAIN for both query .. cheers no offence